# How can I Update to PHP 7 in XAMPP Windows 64b

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using XAMPP Version: 5.6.28, Windows Version:  Enterprise  64-bit
, Control Panel Version: 3.2.2.

I want to upgrade PHP to a >7 version, but all attempts I find result in 
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

I updated httpd-xampp.conf commenting the instructions that load php5ts.dll and libpq.dll, and loaded php7ts.dll and php7apache2.4.dll instead

Then I downloaded VC14 x64 Non Thread Safe and put the contents in a php folder in System/xampp/php, and changed the previous php folder to php_old

I tried running XAMPP as administrator with no success

I searched several solutions on the internet, and  several similar questions in this forum

What could I be missing?

Comment: I find it easier to just update the whole xampp.

Comment: Download current xammp zip archive and extract it. Rename php folder in your xammp folder and copy the php folder from the new package into your xammp folder. If this not works you can undo your changes an update then the whole xammp installation as @Dharman suggested.